# customer custom fields in multiple invoices opencart 2

Tags: opencart, invoice

I have a vqmod which add customers custom_field to invoice.tpl this works fine as long as I hit print button for ONE invoice. But if I select multiple orders and hit print invoice button, only the custom field value from one order (oldest) is displayed.

vqmod below:

```
<file name="admin/controller/sale/order.php">
    <operation>
        <search position="before"><![CDATA[$total_data = array();]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
        $data['account_custom_field'] = $order_info['custom_field'];

        // Custom Fields 
        $this->load->model('customer/custom_field');
        $data['account_custom_fields'] = array();

        $filter_data = array(
            'sort'  => 'cf.sort_order',
            'order' => 'ASC',
        );

        $custom_fields = $this->model_customer_custom_field->getCustomFields($filter_data);

        foreach ($custom_fields as $custom_field) {
            if ($custom_field['location'] == 'account' && isset($order_info['custom_field'][$custom_field['custom_field_id']])) {
                if ($custom_field['type'] == 'text') {
                    $data['account_custom_fields'][] = array(
                        'name'  => $custom_field['name'],
                        'value' => $order_info['custom_field'][$custom_field['custom_field_id']]
                    );
                }
            }
        }

        ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
<file name="admin/view/template/sale/order_invoice.tpl">
   <operation info="add custom field in invoice">
        <search position="after"><![CDATA[<?php echo $order['payment_address']; ?>]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
        <?php if ($account_custom_fields) { ?>
          <br /><br />
          <?php foreach ($account_custom_fields as $custom_field) { ?>
          <b><?php echo $custom_field['name']; ?>:</b> <?php echo $custom_field['value']; ?>
          <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

What did I forget?

Answer (score 0):

1) `$data['account_custom_fields']` should not be part of the `$data` array.  Just make it into a regular variable called `$account_custom_fields` for instance.

2) Once your array is built you need to add it into the `$data['orders']` array just like everything else...

```
$data['orders'][] = array(
    'order_id'              => $order_id,
    'invoice_no'            => $invoice_no,
    'account_custom_fields' => $account_custom_fields,
```

Then access it just like everything else in the template: `$order['account_custom_fields']`

The same goes for your other variable `$data['account_custom_field']`.  The important thing to understand here is that you are inserting code into the controller in the middle of a `foreach` loop which is iterating over orders and building an array - which is then iterated again inside the template.  So anything you want to add on a per order basis and access needs to be added into the $data['orders'] array *for that particular order*.